# C++ Thread: How to pass parameter in main thread to another thread with lambda function

Tags: c++, multithreading, lambda

I am trying to pass a `bool` flag from the main thread to another thread with `lambda` function, but it does not seem to work.
My idea is to create a `LED_thread` blinks LED every one second while the `main thread`does something else. Once the `main task` finishes, the `stop_blink_flag` will turn on and the LED should stop blinking. Here is my work:

```
int main() {
    bool stop_blink_flag = false;

    std::thread LED_thread{ [stop_blink_flag] {
        while (!stop_blink_flag)
        {
            std::cout << "LED is blinking every 1 second\n";
            sleep(1);
        }
        std::cout << "\t\tLED STOP BLINKS\n";
    } };

    // while the main function is running
    std::cout << "\t\Main thread starts...\n";
    std::cout << "I'm gonna do 1\n";
    std::cout << "And I'm gonna do 2\n";
    std::cout << "And I'm gonna sleep for 10s\n";
    sleep(10);
    std::cout << "I just wake up after 10 seconds\n";
    std::cout << "I'm gonna go back to sleep for 3 seconds\n";
    sleep(3);
    std::cout << "I just wake up after 3 seconds\n";
    std::cout << "\t\tSystem stops. Now the LED should stop blinking\n";
    stop_blink_flag = true;
    LED_thread.join(); // main waits for t to finish
}
```

The result shows that the `stop_blink_flag` was not updated from `main thread` to `LED_thread`, so the LED keeps blinking. The detail result is as followed:

```
LED is blinking every 1 second
    Main thread starts...
I'm gonna do 1
And I'm gonna do 2
And I'm gonna sleep for 10s
LED is blinking every 1 second
LED is blinking every 1 second
LED is blinking every 1 second
LED is blinking every 1 second
LED is blinking every 1 second
LED is blinking every 1 second
LED is blinking every 1 second
LED is blinking every 1 second
LED is blinking every 1 second
I just wake up after 10 seconds
I'm gonna go back to sleep for 3 seconds
LED is blinking every 1 second
LED is blinking every 1 second
LED is blinking every 1 second
I just wake up after 3 seconds
        System stops. Now the LED should stop blinking
LED is blinking every 1 second
LED is blinking every 1 second
LED is blinking every 1 second
LED is blinking every 1 second
```

Any help or advice would be very helpful and appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you are passing the variable by value - the lambda makes a copy.

To pass it by reference instead - so the lambda accesses the original variable - just put `&` before it:

```
// before
std::thread LED_thread{ [stop_blink_flag] {

// after                 v
std::thread LED_thread{ [&stop_blink_flag] {
```

Note that since the lambda now accesses the original variable, it's not safe for the lambda to use it after `main` returns (which destroys the variable). In your case, this is safe because `LED_thread.join()` waits for the lambda to return.

Comment: Also an atomic bool should be used (or some other synchronisation) to ensure that read/write are done. Here, there is probably some implicit synchronisation because of `cout`.